# What methods are there for tracking presence in rooms?

Tags: esp8266, iot

Im wanting to automate the lighting in my house, e.g. turn on lights when entering a room without having to fumble around with my phone or switches.

I have looked at audio, PIR and radar sensors, are there any more alternatives? For example using a wifi mesh to triangulate which room a phone is in.

Any suggestions welcome.

P.s. I may end up with one of the earlier options, I just want to see what is out there.

Comment: check out opencv

Comment: Jsotola OpenCV seems a bit excessive for the number of rooms I need to monitor, but for a single location could work

Comment: Maybe a combination of PIR and door-switch (like those used in alarm systems). By combining both you know not to turn of the lights, even if the PIR hasn't picked up any movement for a few minutes, which you're sitting on the couch. I personally really like light-switches. I'm only half joking here. An automated system only rarely has to malfunction for it to be more annoying that having to flick a switch.

Comment: what's wrong with pir and radar?